# Filling an additional field in pivot table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `Event` and `Ticket`. I have implemented `Many to Many` relationship between them:

```
/**
 * Get the tickets for the events.
 */
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ticket');
}
```

And:

```
/**
 * The tickets that belong to the event.
 */
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
}
```

I have also created pivot table called: `event_ticket` and added there 3 fields: `event_id (foreign key)`, `ticket_id (foreign key)` and `ticket_quantity`. While creating a new Event I save it and then I want to `sync` the data into the pivot table like this:

```
$event->tickets()->sync($request->tickets_type);
```

How to fill in the additional `ticket_quantity` field? I'm making like this:

```
$event->tickets()->sync($request->tickets_type, array(
    'ticket_quantity' => 12
));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

> When attaching a relationship to a model, you may also pass an array of additional data to be inserted into the intermediate table:

```
$event->tickets()->attach($ticketId, ['ticket_quantity' => $qty]);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the site `https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many`, in section `Saving Additional Data On A Pivot Table`
, you need to use `save()` method to pass additional data to your pivot table

```
$event->tickets()->save($request->tickets_type, array(
    'ticket_quantity' => 12
));
```